# Foreground service continues to run after stopservice()

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

I was reading android docs about foreground service and it says :

To remove the service from the foreground, call stopForeground(). This method takes a boolean, which indicates whether to remove the status bar notification as well. Note that the service continues to run.

If you stop the service while it's running in the foreground, its notification is removed.

In the last paragraph , it says that only notification is removed.

It means that I can not stop the service completely? and the system does this?

or should I do something?

I use this method to stop the service :

```
stopService(intent);
```

but service is still running when notification is removed.

Here is the simple Service :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    RemoteViews custom;
    NotificationManager notificationmanager;
    Notification notification;
    IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
   
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification_Channel(this);
        startForeground(2,Show_notification(this));
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {

        MyService getService() {

            return MyService.this;
        }


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

   
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String  action = intent.getAction();
        if(action!=null) {
                    switch (action) {

                        case "stop":
                            stopService(intent);
                            stopSelf();
                            break;

                    }


                }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    public void Notification_Channel (Context context) {
        //creating channel
        String offerchannelname = "...";
        String offerchanneldescription = "...";
        int offerchannel_importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel notifchannel = new NotificationChannel( offerchannelid, offerchannelname,offerchannel_importance);
        notifchannel.setDescription(offerchanneldescription);
        // disable sound
        notifchannel.setSound(null,null);
        notificationmanager.createNotificationChannel(notifchannel);

        // using custom Layout
        custom = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.audio_player_notification);

        Show_notification(context);

    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    public Notification Show_notification(Context context) {


        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        Intent clickIntent = new Intent("action1");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                3, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE| PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        custom.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.MyId,pendingIntent);


        Intent clickIntent2 = new Intent("action2");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                4, clickIntent2,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        custom.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.myId_player,pendingIntent);


        Intent clickIntent3 = new Intent("action3");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                5, clickIntent3,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        custom.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.myid,pendingIntent);

     

        Intent open_intent = new Intent(context,Main_Page.class);
        open_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),0,open_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


      return  notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,channel_id)
              
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setOngoing(true)
                  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(custom)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .build();
    }
```

I use these methods to start my service :

```
Intent service_intent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);

ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context,service_intent);
                
                context.bindService(service_intent, this,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I use these methods to stop my service :

```
Intent service_intent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);

 service_intent.setAction("stop");
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context,service_intent);
              
              context.unbindService(service_intent,this);
```

In my Logcat ,this line appears

W/System: A resource failed to call close.

It does not give me much information to find the cause.

Comment: I believe services has a stopSelf function which should stop the service.

Comment: stopForeground() only removes this service from foreground mode, as Dan mentioned to stop service you should use stopSelf() method

Comment: I used that too. also I used stopForeground () . ondestroy() method of service  is called and the notification is removed but service continues to run. I have to mention that it happens when I kill the app by pressing device back button and remove it from recent screen.

Comment: How do you know the service keeps running? If it's been destroyed there's not way it's running, either onDestroy was not called or the service is not running, unless you start it again as soon as you stop it from a different place.

Comment: What are the meaning of the lines         Notification_Channel(this);
and then         startForeground(2,Show_notification(this));
?

Comment: The first one is for creating notification channel , second one is the notification layout I've created for this service.

Comment: I've added Notification_Channel() and  Show_notification()

Comment: I don't know the order of execution here but you specifically call stop before you call start so obviously it will stop and then start, which will make the service running

Comment: Sorry I had misspelling, I have edited the last part. can you do me a favor and check it?   is everything okey ?  I've added my Logcat message.

Comment: How do you know that the `Service` is still running?

Comment: If I do not start it  and kill the app by pressing back button and clear it from recent screen, everything works fine. also  when my app is in the foreground , and I want to stop service , it stops . but when the service is running and I kill the app by pressing back button , my app stucks in the background. I stop the service in the ondestroyview() method of a fragment.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you have started a foreground service for notification but it never get stopped. in order to stop the Foreground service first you need to close the Foreground service using stopForeground(true) inside onStartCommand "stop" action, then you must use stopSelf(startId) to stop the your service.

For more reference please check the below android developer document on stopping service.

[https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping[enter link description here][1]](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I did that but no changes. I get this message in my Logcat :   I/Choreographer: Skipped 398 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I do not know why app does not stop . I've tried several ways. also I have to say that when my app is in the foreground , and I want to stop service , it stops . but when the service is running and I kill the app by preesing back button , my app stucks in the background.

Comment: As I understand from your comment, the main issue is to close the application properly and the app should be removed from recent task. You can use finishAndRemoveTask() and System.exit(0) inside override method onBackPressed to achieve this.

Comment: I found the problem. The problem is that in my main activity, I use movetotaskback(true) and I remove super.onbackpressed() because I want to save the state of the app when I comes to my app from background. however,I cannot use both of them because movetotaskback() does not work. do you have any idea how can I handle this?

Comment: Thank you so much, I could solve my problem with System.exit(0).

Comment: That's great! mention not. @A.G